# require 'coffee-script/register' - unexpected string

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, require

I'm using `coffee-script 1.7.1` (or I want to use it). Can't make it work, though.

first line of my `server.coffee` file is `require 'coffee-script/register'` and I get the oh-so familiar error `SyntaxError: Unexpected string`. On version `1.6.3` all was well.

In a different project I've successfully used `coffee 1.7.1` when the starting file was `server.js`, but don't want to do it here.

Has anyone made this work? Preferably without making some sort of weird workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using coffescript 1.7.1 and require 'coffee-script/register' with server.coffee.

Not sure if this applies to your situation, but I spent many hours on a similar error before I realized that I was launching my app from the wrong instance. For example, `/usr/bin/coffee` instead of `/usr/local/bin/coffee`.

`which coffee` gave me the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you only will need to require `coffee-script/register` when you are writing JS and want to load a coffeescript file.